# Elements of matrix A not in matrix B

Tags: python-2.7, matrix

I'm using 2 matrices of different lengthes ([m,2] and [n,2]). What i'm trying to do is to identify the tuples from A that are not in B. If so, those tuples are saved in another matrix (Err).

```
A=np.matrix([[1,2],
             [3,4],
             [5,6]])
B=np.matrix([[1,2],
            [8,11],
            [16,9]])
Err=[]
for i in A:
  if i not in B:
    Err=i`
Expected answer: Err=[[3,4],[5,6]]
Returned: Err=[[5,6]]
```

This loop actually works with lists but not with matrices. I know this should be very simple but i was stuck all day long.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your previous value is getting overwritten by second value because you are not appending the value to the array and the second value overwrites the first one
use dis :

```
  for i in A:
  if i not in B:
  Err.append=i`
```

Hope this will help you.